# How to change favicon in CKAN

Tags: themes, favicon, ckan

I am having trouble with this seemingly simple task.. 
Can someone help please?

I have uploaded .ico file to `/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/custom_theme/ckanext/custom_theme/public`

Changed value in setting file (`development.ini`)
Tried making base.html for the custom theme, with

```
{% ckan_extends %}
{% block links -%}
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://site.address/favicon.ico" />
{% endblock -%}
```

For file path, I have tried both relative and literal.

I can access the icon file if I type in address of it in web browser.

Comment: If you view source does the <link> look ok?

Comment: @DRead Yes, the link points to the .ico - I can see it when clicking on the link from "view source" of web browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what works for me*:

1. Define favicon filename in your .ini eg. `ckan.favicon = favicon.ico`
2. Upload file to `../ckan/default/src/ckanext-[your_theme]/ckanext/[your_theme]/public`
3. Reload apache
4. Clear Browser cache
5. Reload site in Browser

This assumes CKAN >2.5 and following [instruction on creating a custom theme](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/)

- No need to change the `base.html` file in custom theme.

Comment: In my case it works only if  ckan.favicon = /favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

In CKAN 2.9.0 replace /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/public/base/images/ckan.ico with your ICO file.

Assuming you have:
ckan.favicon = /base/images/ckan.ico in your ckan.ini

Refresh your browser.